# Opencart 2 load layout by id

Tags: opencart2.x

In opencart I have Information layout id, it's custom not default. How I can load custom layout by this id ?

It posible to have custom template in one of information pages ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//loading Layout
```

**=>** While adding/Editing Information page under the Design Tab you can overwrite layout dynamically which is preferable.
[image]

**=>** or you can pass manually `layout_id` based on your condition on each file `contente_top, content_button, column_left and Column_right`, which i dont recommand.

`$modules = $this->model_design_layout->getLayoutModules($layout_id, 'column_left');`

```
//Creating Layout
```

To create a custom layout, you first need to create New Controller & View ([findhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13478995/how-to-become-an-opencart-guru)), after that you can add your own layout by going on`admin/system/design/layout` for your new `Controller(Rout)`

```
//loading custom template
```

if you want to load custom template for particular information page, you can pass `custom tpl` file on your condition, create `yourfile.tpl`

go to `catalog/controller/information/information.php:49`

here check the condition and pass your view tile.

```
if($information_id==your_condition){
   $this->response->setOutput($this->load->view($this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/information/yourfile.tpl', $data));
}else{
   $this->response->setOutput($this->load->view($this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/information/information.tpl', $data));
}
```