# How to create a custom layout for specific information pages in Opencart 2

Tags: opencart, opencart2.x, opencart-module

I'm trying to create a custom layout for an information page in Opencart 2, it does not appear to be working at all. Here is what was done:

- copied /catalog/view/theme/_my_theme/information/information.tpl to
  /catalog/view/theme/_my_theme/information/newproducts.tpl and made some minor changes
- copied /catalog/controller/information/information.php to /catalog/controller/information/newproducts.php
- in the new file:
  -- updated the class to: class ControllerInformationNewproducts extends Controller
  -- updated any instance of information/information to information/newproducts
- I even copied the /catalog/model/catalog/information.php to newproducts.php

In opencart admin I created a new layout Design->Layouts->New Layout with a route of: information/newproducts

then in my "new products" information page [in opencart admin] I changed the layout override to the new products layout.

Nothing, no changes to the information page, so I added a debug line to the aoutput array in the information controller[s]

```
$data['debugger'] = 'this is the newproducts controller';
```

and

```
$data['debugger'] = 'this is the default information controller';
```

the debug being sent to my live page is the default information controller, Opencart is not even trying to use the newproducts controller.

How is this supposed to be done correctly?

Comment: You wont be needing a new layout.. You have made the tpl file that is just fine. Now in the new controller, at the end of index.php, which tpl file are you calling?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32395406/opencart-2-load-layout-by-id/32420113#32420113